# unable to read IF in printing outputs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement, random

For the following code, Python recommended me to use `a.any`.
Now, according to my code what the outputs show is wrong.
`l` is bigger than `1` but the out put is printing `r` instead of `q=10`.

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np

for i in range (1,3):
    r=np.random.uniform(0,3,i)
    x=np.random.uniform(0,9,i)    
    h=np.random.uniform(0,1,i)
    l=r+x
    if (l<1.0).any:
        q=r
    elif (l>1.0).any:
        q=10
    print("q= ",q,"l= ",l)
```

Comment: You have to _call_ `any`: `if (l<1.0).any():`

Comment: @Aran   Ah what the bad mistakes. Thank you my friend. Thank you.
and do you know how to change the out puts of this code from arrays to regular number? output is[0.000121] but I need 0.000121. Thank you again

Comment: @David q and l will contain either 1,2 or 3 elements, how do you want to print them?

Comment: @David you can use * to unpack iterables like: ```print(*l)```

Comment: @con error:print() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Comment: @FlyingTeller I want to print the `q` and `l`, then find their minimum value in the output.

Comment: @David the problem is probably if (l>1.0).any() is true, q becomes 10 (an int) instead of a numpy array (an iterable). You could just make q=np.array([10]) to handle that edge case.

Comment: @con-- thank you. I have another questions about finding minimum and order of printing. should I open a new question? or ask here again?

Comment: @David probably best to open a new question, this comment section is getting quite long

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your questions. This one can be scrutinized by changing the random number.
using `np.random.uniform(0,1)` does not need `any()` if you just want random number. But if it is important to have specific numbers for each `i` you must use `any()`.

```
for i in range (1,3):
    r=np.random.uniform(0,3)
    x=np.random.uniform(0,9)    
    h=np.random.uniform(0,1)
    l=r+x
    if l<1.0:
        q=r
    elif l>1.0:
        q=10
    print("q= ",q,"l= ",l)
```